# What is the origin and meanining of -ка in these words/Какова этимология и смысл -ка в этих словах?

Tags: морфология, история-языка, психолингвистика, фоносемантика

Рассмотрим такие слова как *ласка, тоска, доска, миска, полоска, колбаска, опаска, ряска*. Морфемно-орфографический словарь выдает следующее разделение (в скобках - информация по Фасмеру):

> ласк.а (сопоставл. с болг. "лаская" = русск. "льщу", лат.lascivus); тоск.а (возм. связ. с "тощий"); доск.а ("дощатый"); миск.а (этимологии нет);
>   опек.а (связано с "печаль"); ряск.а (растение, этимологии нет); коляск.а (коло-, колесо, ср.с тохарским kälaskam - одна из форм косв.п., по Иванову)

Но:

> лас.о.ч.к.а, дос.о.ч.к.а, ряс.о.ч.к.а, коляс.о.ч.к.а, о.глас.к.а, о.пас.к.а, полос.к.а, колбас.к.а, ряс.к.а

Раздел на морфемы кажется слишком произвольным - при том, что в русском и др. славянских языках есть примеры чередования согласных, а в древних родственных языках - когнаты означенных слов.

Сравни с санскритским -ка, присутствующим в словах для обозначения неодушевленных объектов.

Что такое -ка в этих словах? Как оно появлялось исторически и может ли быть связано с (пра)индоевропейскими суффиксами?  Не является ли это (с)ка в действительности вариативным консонантным кластером (наподобие древнегреческого кс или болгарсого щ), воспринимаемым носителями языка как две разных согласных?

= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

What is the meaning and history of -ка among the Russian words listed above (given the fact that there is for sht in Bulgarian and even in Russian language the stem consonants alternate).

Does the fact of cognate words (e.g. in Tocharian kälaskam for Russian "коляска" according to Ivanov) and -ka in Sanskrit words for inanimate/istrumentive objects have something to do with this?

Is it in fact a single consonant claster (like Greek x or Bulgarian щ) which is perceived by native Russian speakers as two separate consonants?
The division into stem/root consonants seems to be too arbitrary.

Answer (score 6):

Вы как-то странно смешали несколько разных вопросов в одном, и упомянутый ряд слов слишком разнороден. Как минимум, следовало бы разделить на слова, у которых как минимум это -к- в -ка входит в основу как минимум в раннеобщеславянские времена, затем те, у которых это часть основы только в поздние времена (история русского языка после отделения), и те, у которых видно происхождение и сейчас.

Например, "полоска" однозначно увязывается с "полоса" стандартным способом (-к- как уменьшительный суффикс) любым носителем языка. Таких примеров в языке сотни. Во всех этих случаях этимология рассказывает про уменьшительный суффикс -ък-, который дал беглый гласный (им.ед. полоска - род.мн. полосок). Для "ласка" этимология сложнее, но тоже можно предполагать, что -к- - суффикс, хоть и более древний. В то же время, для "тоска" тут -к- есть согласный корня, и иной вариант не прослеживается.

Далее, морфемно-орфографический словарь показывает текущее состояние с точки зрения носителей языка, а не историю, которая может не согласовываться с ним и даже противоречить. Хрестоматийный пример - голландское zonnedoek ("навес от солнца") превратилось в "зонтик", а далее образовалось "зонт". С точки зрения истории тут нелепица, а с точки зрения морфологии тут уменьшительный суффикс -ик-. Поэтому морфемно-орфографический словарь показывает те слова, которые делятся на морфемы для современного языкового сознания, так, как они делятся.

Что за санскритское -ка, Вы не уточнили (лучше бы пару примеров), но история чётко показывает, что никакого подобного явления в этом ряду слов нет.

Comment: +1. See also *колготки/колготы*, *брелоки/брелки* etc.

Comment: тоска/тощий, доска/дощатый, и т.д.

Comment: Санскритское -ка: चषक (= чашака) - чашка, राका (раака) - лунный свет,  पाक (паака)- домашний очаг, लक (лака) - лоб, и т.д. Сотни слов на -ка, преобладающее значение = неодушевленный объект.

Comment: @Quassnoi it's clear about  колготки/колготы, or брелоки/брелки. I'm curious about earlier words.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, *ласочка*, *досочка* и *рясочка* — просто реэтимологизация, и никакой древности тут нет, а наоборот, сравнительно позднее явление, когда до этимологически правильных *лащечка* и *рящечка* (ср. *дощечка*) языковая интуиция уже "не дотягивалась", так что формы образовывались по аналогии с теми, где *-к-* выступает как суффикс. Или, возможно, язык отмел эти правильные формы из-за их неблагозвучия, которое в "дощечке" смягчено положением ударения.

Answer (score 1):

In Russian "-к-" is a deminutive suffix, which comes from Proto-Indo-European -ik-.

So yes, коляска and the Tocharian words couls be derived with the same suffix.